# How to integrate over spikes in the context of signal processing?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing

[image]

In this question, say I have to integrate from F=3 to F=4, wrt F. We encounter one spike in this range. How are these spike integrals defined and how do I evaluate it?

Comment: The graph is incomplete, there is no information telling us the "strength" of the spike (usually written in parentheses  next to the spike). The "strength" tells us what the spike integrates to.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I think the area can also be given by the height of the arrow (1 in this case). https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function This article has this information in the main image description

Comment: @NinadMunshi My full question is here :https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/61287/find-integral-of-dtft-after-sampling-graph-of-ctft-given

Comment: This is one of those things where if your class chose a convention, great, but no one outside the class is going to be able to help you. I would definitely not assume that the height of the arrows means the spikes are unit impulses (after all, an infinite spike can be represented by an arrow of arbitrary size, and the height could have just been a formatting coincidence) without talking to your professor first.

Comment: @NinadMunshi But wikipedia says that the height convention is also a popular one. The other convention is to write the area beside the arrow. Btw, assuming that this height does mean the area, does that mean that the integral from 3 to 4 is 1? Or is it just that the integral of -infinity to infinity is 1?

Comment: From my point of view my contribution to the conversation is over as I have nothing definitive to offer. Eyeballing heights like that is something I never did over the course of 4 signal processing classes, but drawing different heights was done. With ambiguity, what is the harm in asking your professor? It could very well be that they are unit impulses (the "strength"/height of the impulse and area do mean the same thing) but I wouldn't say its a general reasonable assumption unless your class has already agreed upon its meaning.

Comment: @NinadMunshi It's actually an online viedo course (not live), so I can't ask anyone over there. If we do assume that the height is the area, then the integral from 3 to 4 would be 1, right?